# Installed Zone Alarm on Amazon EC2 Windows Instance and cannot access now. How do I fix this?

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall

I messed up this.
Installed ZoneMinder and now I cannot connect to my VPS via Remote Desktop, it must probably have blocked connections. Didnt know it will start blocking right away and let me configure it before.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this a Windows or Linux instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: My answer is under the assumption this is a Windows instance due to the use of 'Remote Desktop', even though ZoneMinder is primarily Linux-based.**

Short answer is you probably can't and will likely be forced to terminate the instance.

But at the very least you can take a snapshot of the hard drive (EBS volume) attached to the machine, so you don't lose any data or configuration settings.

Without network connectivity your server can't be accessed at all, and unless you've installed other services on the machine that are still accessible (e.g. ssh, telnet) that could be used to reverse the firewall settings, you can't make any changes.

I would attempt the following in this order (although they're longshots):

Restart your instance using the AWS Console (maybe the firewall won't be enabled by default on reboot and you'll be able to connect).

If this doesn't work (which it shouldn't), you're going to need to stop your crippled instance, detach the volume, spin up another ec2 instance running Windows, and attach the old volume to the new instance.

[Here's the procedure with screenshots of the exact steps](http://www.smattie.com/2012/01/03/ec2-windows-20082008r2-loss-of-connectivity-due-to-windows-firewall/), except your specific steps to disable the new firewall will be different.

After this is done, you need to find instructions on manually uninstalling your new firewall -

1. Take a snapshot of the EBS volume attached to it to preserve your data (essentially the C:), this appears on the EC2 console page under the 'volumes' menu item. This way you don't lose any data at least.
2. Start another Windows EC2 instance, and attach the EBS volume from the old one to this one. RDP into the new instance and attempt to manually uninstall the firewall.

At a minimum at this point you should be able to recover your files and service settings very easily into the new instance, which is the approach I would expect you to have more success with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to create another instance and migrate everything as you told me. Had a couple of complications but finally managed to restore everything. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it. It might be worth listing the complications you had and how you solved them, and then marking this as the answer to help others with the same problem.